# Binary and Denary converter in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am quite new to python and i want to create a binary to decimal converter and a decimal to binary converter.

**However** the binary number the user wants to convert can only be eight digits long and has to be a valid binary number, and the deciamal number the user wants to convert can only be positive and up to 255.

I came up with this code and I'm stuck with the **'However'** part.

```
import time

def program():
    a = input ("Would you like to convert Denary To Binary (D) or Binary To Denary (B)? ")

if a == ("D") :

    def denary():
        print("The denary number you want to convert, can only be a positive number up to 255")
        time.sleep(2)
        e= int(input("What number would you like to convert into Binary? "))
        if e < 255 or e==255 or e >= 0:
            print(bin(e)[2:].zfill(8))
            again=int(input("Would you like to go again YES[1] NO[2]"))
            if again==(1):
                program()
            else:   
                print ("Thank you for using the program")    

        else:
            denary()


    denary()




elif a == ("B"):

    def binary():
        print("The binary number you want to convert, can only be eight digits long and can only be a valid binary, number consiting of 0's and 1's")
        time.sleep(2)    
        c = int(input("What Binary number would you like to convert into Denary? "))
        if len(c) >8 and c== '0' or '1':
            convert= lambda b: str(int(b, 2))
            print(c + " is " + convert(c) + " in Denary")
            again=int(input("Would you like to convert a number again YES[1] NO[2]"))
            if again==(1):
                program()

            else:
                print ("Thank you for using the program") 

        else:
            binary()

    binary()    


else:
    program()

program()
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but what is `Denary`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget base 10

Comment: another word for decimal, thats what my teacher uses.

Comment: Cool! I learned something new today :)

Comment: Please fix your code formatting

Comment: Just [how old](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=denary&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdenary%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdenary%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDenary%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDENARY%3B%2Cc0) is your teacher? :)

Comment: probably 30 or something ;), and im not using denary again, i think ill stick with decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if e < 255 or e==255 or e >= 0:
```

You don't want `or` here. This branch will be taken if at least one of the conditions is true. 1000 satisfies `e >= 0`, so 1000 will pass the check. -1000 satisfies `e < 255`, so -1000 will pass the check. In fact, every number will pass through here. You want

```
if e >= 0 and e <= 255:
```

or, using Python's comparison chaining,

```
if 0 <= e <= 255:
```

---

```
        if len(c) >8 and c== '0' or '1':
```

This makes no sense.

- First, `c` is already an `int`; you're trying to manipulate it as a string.
- Second, the length test shouldn't be checking that the length is *greater* than 8. It should be `== 8` if you need an exact match or `<= 8` if any length up to 8 works.
- Third, the part of this after the `and` makes no sense. `x == y or z` doesn't test whether `x` is equal to one of `y` or `z`. It's interpreted as `(x == y) or z`, which is usually nonsense.
- Finally, even if `c== '0' or '1'` tested whether `c` were one of `'0'` or `'1'`, that still wouldn't be a meaningful thing to do. If you want to test whether all the characters in `c` are `'0'` or `'1'`, you can use `all` with a generator expression:

  all(char in ('0', '1') for char in c)

Addressing all those issues, we have the following:

```
c = input("What Binary number would you like to convert into Denary? ")
if len(c) == 8 and all(char in ('0', '1') for char in c):
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this sense to just a beginner in programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the basic conversion functions that should get you going:

```
def dec2bin(N):
    if not N:
        return ''
    else:
        return dec2bin(N//2) + str(N%2)

def bin2dec(b):
    answer = 0
    for char in b:
        answer *= 2
        answer += int(char)
    return answer

def program():
    answer = input("Do you want to convert decimal to binary (D) or ...: ")
    if answer == "D":
        N = int(input("Enter your number: "))
        print("The binary of %s is %s" %(N, dec2bin(N)))

    # remainder of the UI logic goes here
```

Comment: While this may be helpful, the OP's real problem is bad boolean logic.

Comment: Im sorry, im new to python. how should i implement what you have told me to my program?

Comment: Use these two functions. Then when you need to convert between binary and denary, call the functions to do the conversions. The rest is asking the user for inputs, which you have already done correctly. Feel free to ask more

Comment: So instead of using my way of converting between decimal to binary and vice verse i use your subroutine? When i use the first sub rotine and do what you say, it comes up with error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Computer science/Python/binary and denary v2.py", line 64, in <module>
    program()
  File "F:/Computer science/Python/binary and denary v2.py", line 34, in program
    denary()
  File "F:/Computer science/Python/binary and denary v2.py", line 24, in denary
    dec2bin(N)
NameError: global name 'N' is not defined

Comment: Don't define functions inside other functions. That's just asking for trouble. Look at my edit

Comment: Ohhh, thanks now i understand more thanks for your time and effort,  now ive got two ways of doing my program now :)

Comment: If you cannot understand what I'm saying, that only says that I am unable to communicate well with you; for that I apologize. Please don't feel bad. Stick with it and hopefully, you'll figure it out soon

Comment: No, its alright, i understood after studying it after the edit, thanks for your help :) really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

leverage your builtins!

dec to bin:

```
def to_bin(n): #assuming n is a str
    """If the str n represents a number in the range [0, 256), return a
    binary string representation of that number, otherwise raise a ValueError

    """
    if 0 <= int(n) < 256:  # if n is in the valid range
        return bin(int(n))[2:] #builtin :p
    else:
        raise ValueError('number must be in range [0, 256)')
```

bin to dec

```
def to_dec(n):
    """If the str n is at most 8 characters long and consists only of '0' and
    '1' characters, return the decimal string representation of it, otherwise
    raise a ValueError

    """
    if len(n) <= 8 all(c in ('0', '1') for c in n):
        return str(int(n, 2))
    else:
        raise ValueError('binary number must be <= 8 digits and consist of 0 and 1')
```

Comment: Also another way of doing my program, thanks for your time and effort :)